# After Ubuntu installation Windows 8 cannot be loaded from GRUB menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, grub, ubuntu-13.10

After 3 weeks of trying, today I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my system. My system was already running on Windows 8 Pro. I installed Ubuntu by manually selecting a drive. The installation was successfully completed and it asked me to reboot. I did it after removing the disk. When the GRUB menu appeared I selected Ubuntu. Then a pink screen appeared and nothing else happened. I waited for sometime and now too nothing happened. So I restarted again and selected Windows in the GRUB menu. Then an error came saying like "Cannot load from disk". How can I solve these issues ?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't follow instruction I would repair the Windows 8 bootloader and see if that helps.

Comment: @Ramhound How to repair the Windows 8 bootloader ?